# How to pass arguments to a Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-compose, docker-registry, dockerhub

I am using RUN instruction within a `Dockerfile` to install a rpm

```
RUN yum -y install samplerpm-2.3
```

However, I want to pass the value "2.3" as an argument.
My RUN instruction should look something like:

```
RUN yum -y install samplerpm-$arg
```

where `$arg=2.3`

Answer (score 426, accepted):

**As of Docker 1.9**, You are looking for `--build-arg` and the `ARG` instruction.

Check out [this document for reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#arg). This will allow you to add `ARG arg` to the `Dockerfile` and then build with

```
docker build --build-arg arg=2.3 .
```

Comment: After doing all that, I am getting an error  **No package samplerpm-$arg available. ** It seems the argument value of 2.3 is not getting substituted.

Comment: what about env variables instead?

Comment: Environment variables are a _runtime_ variable. The build arguments are a _build_ time variable. The distinction here is declaring variables that you only want to use for building the image and do not want (or should not) store for runtime of the container.

Answer (score 5):

If you have multiple FROM statements in dockerfile, make sure to redeclare the variable/s with no value for each variable/s or they'll be lost when it exits the block.

Here's an article that writes more about this: [Why are my Docker ARGs empty?](https://benkyriakou.com/posts/docker-args-empty)

Here's an example:

```
ARG VERSION=latest
FROM ubuntu:${VERSION}

ARG VERSION
ARG FILENAME
COPY ${FILENAME} /home/ubuntu/${FILENAME}
```

Comment: Note that since VERSION isn't reused (in the fragment shown), you don't actually need to repeat "ARG VERSION" after the FROM statement.